# Bootstrap: container with absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="banner-wrapper">
    <div class="banner-image" style="background-image: url(...);"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                SOME ARBITRARILY LONG TEXT
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the corresponding SCSS:

```
.banner-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;

  .banner-image {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
  }

  .container {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

What I want is the text to appear on top of the image conserving the responsive margins that come with a container. The image is full width (like it was inside a container-fluid).

The problem is that setting `position: absolute` on the container seems to break it. Is there a better way to achieve this?

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8801/

Comment: can you give me the link from jsfiddle, so that I can get a clear idea of your problem?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8801/ @JafferWilson

Comment: What output you expect. The output is not available....I am still unable to understand your problem

Comment: @JafferWilson I updated the fiddle.. I would like the text inside the gray area to behave like the one outside... they're both inside containers, except one is absolutely positioned inside another div

Comment: So, you want the complete text in the gray part to be out side..Can you send some images just for my clarification of the output you want..ok

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need an absolute wrapper for your container, instead of making that container absolute, keeping bootstrap clean.

i've modified your jsfiddle to below.. kindly accept if this is what you were looking for, thanks.

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

.banner-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.banner-image {
  width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: gray;
}

.absolute-wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:50%;
}

.container {
    text-align: center;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-wrapper">
    <div class="banner-image"></div>
    <div class ="absolute-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    SOME VERY LONG TEXT IN AN ABSOLUTE DIV
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                SOME ARBITRARILY LONG TEXT WITH CORRECT MARGINS
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Nice solution, perfect !

Answer (score 0):

Set background image position:absolute

```css
.banner-image {
  width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: gray;
    position:absolute;
}
```