# Prevent container div from covering absolute-relative div in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

When `site-header` is set to relative, the bootstrap `container`div moves up into the site-header space like this:

[image]

**How do I make the header look like this?**

[image]

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795514/bootstrap-container-with-absolute-positioning)

```css
   

.site-header {
    padding-left: 77.2px;
    padding-right: 77.2px;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.headerImage {
    height: 483px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.headerText {
    padding: 6% 4%;
    width: 60%;
    position: relative;
    left: 40%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 2;
}

.row.standardPageContent {
  margin-top: 250px;
}
```

```html
  

 <header class="site-header">
               <img class="headerImage" src="images/cornellCoverImageWetLab.png">
                <div class="headerText">
                    <div class="title">Wet Lab</div>
                    <div class="subtitle">We did some cool stuff and wrote this tagline</div>
                </div>
        </header>

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar" class="container">
        <div class="row standardPageContent">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#overview">OVERVIEW</a></li>
            <li><a href="#biobricks">BIOBRICKS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#chassis">CHASSIS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#results">RESULTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#futurework">FUTURE WORK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#references">REFERENCES</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>

    <!-- Page Content -->
        <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-9 content">

                 <h1><a id="overview">Overview</a></h1>
                    <p>Paragraph writings will go here
                    </p>
                 <h1><a id="biobricks">Biobricks</a></h1>
                 <h1><a id="chassis">Chassis</a></h1>
                 <h1><a id="results">Results</a></h1>
                 <h1><a id="futurework">Future Work</a></h1>
                 <h1><a id="references">References</a></h1>

           </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide full code for that page (at least header and overview container row), I'll give you the solution.

Please have a look on this concept for achieve that your target structure.

```css
*,
 :after,
 :before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.site-header {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: orange;
  display: table;
}

.site-header .headerImage {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.site-header .headerText {
  background: rgba(213, 123, 75, 0.6);
  padding: 10% 10% 10% 40%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.site-header .headerText .inner {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 30px 50px;
}

.site-header .headerText .inner .title {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.overview-container-with-sidebar {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: brown;
  float: left;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.overview-container {
  width: 70%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<header class="site-header">
  <img class="headerImage" src="http://via.placeholder.com/990x250">
  <div class="headerText">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="title">Wet Lab</div>
      <div class="subtitle">We did some cool stuff and wrote this tagline</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<section class="overview-container-with-sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li>Links</li>
      <li>Links</li>
      <li>Links</li>
      <li>Links</li>
      <li>Links</li>
      <li>Links</li>
      <li>Links</li>
      <li>Links</li>
      <li>Links</li>
      <li>Links</li>
      <li>Links</li>
      <li>Links</li>
      <li>Links</li>
      <li>Links</li>
      <li>Links</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="overview-container">
    <h2>Overview</h2>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia
      voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi
      tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui
      in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia
      voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi
      tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui
      in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: hi I updated my picture and code. The sidebar & overview content isn't stacking underneath the banner pic and I'm not sure how to vertically center banner text in relation to the banner pic (adding `magin-top` to `.headerImage` doesn't work)